# Cut lies if delimeter doesn’t exist

Tags: bash-scripting, cut

For example:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<< "example"
example
```

Why does cut lie to me telling me that “example” is the second delimeter and on. I want it to print `""` since there is no second delimeter.

Note this does the right thing:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<< "example "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-s` option:

```
$ cut -d ' ' -sf 2- <<< "example"
$
```

By default, if a line has no delimiters, `cut` will print the entire line.  `-s` turns this behavior off.

Not that your second example, does have a delimiter:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 2- <<< "example "
```

Because the line has a delimiter, `cut` does what you expect.

#### Documentation

This behavior is documented in `man cut`:

> **-f, --fields=LIST**
>       select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified